# How to close a window using selenium in python with html as follows

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am using selenium in python to try to close a window, but the close button has html as follows, so  what shall my driver selects to close it?

```
<div class="close-button-container"><a href="#0" class="overlay-panel-close fg-close-tab-gtm">Close</a></div>
```

Comment: Don't ask for a code. Share what have you tried and describe your issue

Comment: share your exception stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("your_link")
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='overlay-panel-close fg-close-tab-gtm']")
elem.click()
```

Comment: You cannot pass compound class name to `find_element_by_class_name`

Comment: @Andersson thanks for your comment. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: You should add single quotes around class name

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is within a *Overlay Panel* so you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Close"))).click()
  ```
- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.close-button-container>a.overlay-panel-close.fg-close-tab-gtm"))).click()
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='overlay-panel-close fg-close-tab-gtm' and contains(.,'Close')]"))).click()
  ```